# HR Height not matching the markdown preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, markdown-preview

Apologies if this is a dupe, I couldn't find it.

The `<hr>` styling for the preview and the actual posts doesn't quite match up, there's an extra style affecting the preview:

```
form hr{border:1px solid #ccc;width:100%;text-align:left;}
```

This makes the preview look like this:

[image: Markdown Preview]

And the actual look like this:
[image: Actual Rendering]

The actual is a nice clean 1px line, but due to the `form hr` rule overriding the `border: 0` `hr` rule in the preview, it doesn't look quite right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minor discrepency between markdown preview and rendered question for horizontal rule](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27424/minor-discrepency-between-markdown-preview-and-rendered-question-for-horizontal-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch -- this was some old useless CSS rule. Removed.